# How to calculate the amount of SQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table transaction_details:

| transaction_id | customer_id | item_id | item_number | transaction_dttm |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7765 | 1 | 23 | 1 | 2022-01-15 |
| 1254 | 2 | 12 | 4 | 2022-02-03 |
| 3332 | 3 | 56 | 2 | 2022-02-15 |
| 7658 | 1 | 43 | 1 | 2022-03-01 |
| 7231 | 4 | 56 | 1 | 2022-01-15 |
| 7231 | 2 | 23 | 2 | 2022-01-29 |

I need to calculate the amount spent by the client in the last month and find out the item (item_name) on which the client spent the most in the last month.

Example result:
|customer_id|amount_spent_lm|top_item_lm|
| - | ---------- | ----- |
| 1 | 700 | glasses |
| 2 | 20000 | notebook |
| 3 | 100 | cup |

When calculating, it is necessary to take into account the current price at the time of the transaction (dict_item_prices). Customers who have not made purchases in the last month are not included in the final table. he last month is defined as the last 30 days at the time of the report creation.

There is also a table dict_item_prices:

| item_id | item_name | item_price | valid_from_dt | valid_to_dt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | phone 1 | 1000 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-12-31 |
| 12 | notebook | 5000 | 2022-01-02 | 2022-12-31 |
| 56 | cup | 50 | 2022-01-02 | 2022-12-31 |
| 43 | glasses | 700 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-12-31 |

Comment: Use SUM() for the calculations, other aggregate functions are available as well

Comment: Can you show me, I don't understand how to do it.

Comment: You need better test data, for example transaction_id 7231 maps to two different customers and won't have a price for item_id 56. And what is item_number? The number of items or something else? And what should be the outcome for the example?

Comment: I added the result to the description. Yes, item_number is the quantity of the item.